# symfony: permalinks (hide id in urls)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, permalinks

I've read the paragraph about permalinks (hide primary keys and replace them with significant strings) but I can't understand how it works this code:

```
public function executePermalink($request)
  {
    $article = ArticlePeer::retrieveBySlug($request->getParameter('slug');
    $this->forward404Unless($article);  // Display 404 if no article matches slug
    $this->article = $article;          // Pass the object to the template
  }
```

This code is typical of propel, is it right? there is something like it for doctrine? I've to write the retrieveBySlug() function? do you have an example where I can understand how to write it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Doctrine you have an extension called "Sluggable" you can use.

To make it work you have to change your schema.yml and add the "Sluggable" extension:

```
# config/doctrine/schema.yml
Article:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      fields: [name]
  columns:
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull:  true
```

Set up a DoctrineRoute in your routing.yml

```
# apps/frontend/config/routing.yml
category:
  url:      /article/:slug
  class:    sfDoctrineRoute
  param:    { module: article, action: show }
  options:  { model: Article, type: object }
```

Then in your code for the action you can do something like this :

```
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
{
    $this->article = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->forward404Unless($article);  // Display 404 if no article matches slug
    $this->article = $article;          // Pass the object to the template
}
```

Don't forget to run a doctrine:build to recreate the database after you alter your schema.

Comment: @ilanco you can remove the check with `forward404Unless` since `$this->getRoute()->getObject()` already perform the check.

Comment: Hi, I've tried it... It gave me some problems, but I've solved it (in the answer I explain how I've done it...)

Answer (score 0):

now is working fine!

```
# apps/frontend/config/routing.yml
opera_slug:
  url:   /:sf_culture/opere/:operaslug.html
  class:    sfDoctrineRoute
  param: { module: opera, action: permalink }
  options:  { model: Opera, type: object }
  requirements:
    sf_culture: (?:it|en|es|fr)



  public function executePermalink(sfWebRequest $request)
  {  
    $this->opera = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
    $this->forward404Unless($this->opera);  // Display 404 if no article matches slug
    //$this->opera = $opera;          // Pass the object to the template  
  }
```

As you can see, I've modified last two rows of executePermalink(), because I had an error using your function

Comment: Nice but you can replace .html by .:sf_format and add to requiremet sf_format: html